# Problem with keylistener

Tags: java, swing

hi i'm using swing and in my main frame(JFrame) i want that when ever user press + key one window lets say test should appear.
my key listener works fine if i don't call the show method of the newly added JInternalFrame  but when i call the show method of my JInternalFrame the KeyListener stops listening any more.

i've tried a lot to solve it but all in vain so any help regarding this will be appreciated.
thanks.

this is my keyListener

```
_mainFrameKeyListener = new KeyListener()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("the key pressed Id is : " + arg0.getKeyCode());

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == 107){
                test Test = new test();
                _mainDesktopPane.add(Test);
                Test.show();

            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }           
};
```

Comment: test Test = new test(); - Made me cringe :)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html

Comment: So it works once, but when the internal frame is shown it stops? Is it because the just opened internal frame has focus maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a hot key instead of a key listener to avoid focus issues.

```
// Get the KeyStroke for our hot key

KeyStroke plus = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, 0, true);

// Get the input map for our component
// In this case we are interested in key strokes in the focussed window

InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

// Map the key stroke to our "action key" (see below)

inputMap.put(plus, "my_action");

// Get the action map for our component

ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

// Add the required action listener to out action map

actionMap.put("my_action", actionListener);
```

http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-specify-a-hot-key-for-a-swing-application

Comment: How about an answer, rather than a link?

Comment: the link contains the example code that shows how to do what I have suggested, ie. add a hot ket instead of using a key listener

Comment: Unfortunatelly "KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, 0, true)" doesn't work for me. But "KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('+')" works fine. Maybe that this comment can help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the key listener to exactly the component that has focus (many components are actually composites).

So use `JComponent.registerKeyboardAction` with a condition of `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Alternatively use `JComponent.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, true)` and `JComponent.getActionMap(true)` as described in the `registerKeyboardAction` API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether a runtime exception is thrown. may be you are in the wrong thread for showing this dialog or another issue could throw this exception.

Also please think about to use a asynch thread for showing your dialog instead of using the listener thread. But this is just a think about.

Comment: i didn't get your reply!
i was dealing with Key press event not any multi threading issue. 
and anyway problem is solved.